# Issues with *ngFor and GridLayout in Nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript, ngfor, nativescript-angular, ng-container

I have a problem with the grid layout. My code is this one:

```
    <GridLayout padding="10%"columns="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" rows="*">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <label [text]="item.codice" col="0",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.prodotto" col="1",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.lottoData" col="2",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.codiceCont" col="3",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.qtyUntPri" col="4",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.studioCieco" col="5",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.qty" col="6",[row]="{{item.row}}"fontSize="24px"></label>
      </ng-container>
    </GridLayout>
```

I'm expecting to see those columns and a row for each item, but I have something like you can see in the image below:

[image]

If you need to see the typescript

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    var usefulData = this.data["param"]["response"];
    var firstTable = usefulData[0];
    var secondTable = usefulData[1];
    this.studyCode = firstTable[0]["StudyCode"];
    this.nameFile = firstTable[0]["NameFile"];
    var row = 1;
    for (var i in secondTable){
      if(secondTable[i] != undefined){
        this.items.push({
        codice:secondTable[i]["Codice"],
        prodotto:secondTable[i]["Product"],
        lottoData:secondTable[i]["LottoData"],
        codiceCont:secondTable[i]["CodiceCont"],
        qtyUntPri:secondTable[i]["QtyUntPri"],
        studioCieco:secondTable[i]["StudioCieco"],
        qty:secondTable[i]["Qty"],
        row:row
      });
      row+=1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the `GridLayout` with `rows="*"`, which means that you have **only one row**:

```
<GridLayout padding="10%"columns="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" rows="*">
```

This is why you're seeing the overlapping condensed text in the screenshot you provided.

Reminder: The `rows` and `columns` of {N} GridLayout take either:

- An absolute number: Indicates a fixed size.
- auto: Makes the column as wide as its widest child or makes the row as tall as its tallest child.
- *: Takes as much space as available after filling all auto and fixed-size columns or rows.

To fix this, you need to set the `rows` property to reflect the number of rows that should be available on your `GridLayout`. For example, if you have an item with `[row]="{{item.row}}"`, and the maximum `item.row` = 5, then your `GridLayout` should be declared like below:

```
<GridLayout
    padding="10%"
    columns="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto"
    rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" <-- note the 5 rows
>
    <!-- child elements ... -->
</GridLayout>
```

In your example it looks like you have to calculate the number of rows and bind this to the `rows` property of the `Gridlayout`, like so:

```
    public gridRows: string;


    ngOnInit(): void {
        var usefulData = this.data['param']['response'];
        var firstTable = usefulData[0];
        var secondTable = usefulData[1];
        this.studyCode = firstTable[0]['StudyCode'];
        this.nameFile = firstTable[0]['NameFile'];
        var row = 1;
        for (var i in secondTable) {
            if (secondTable[i] != undefined) {
                this.items.push({
                    codice: secondTable[i]['Codice'],
                    prodotto: secondTable[i]['Product'],
                    lottoData: secondTable[i]['LottoData'],
                    codiceCont: secondTable[i]['CodiceCont'],
                    qtyUntPri: secondTable[i]['QtyUntPri'],
                    studioCieco: secondTable[i]['StudioCieco'],
                    qty: secondTable[i]['Qty'],
                    row: row,
                });
                row += 1;
            }
        }

        const rowsCount = row;
        this.gridRows = Array.from({ length: rowsCount }, (_, idx) => `auto`).toString();
    }
```

```
<GridLayout
    padding="10%"
    columns="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto"
    [rows]="gridRows"
>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <label [text]="item.codice" col="0" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.prodotto" col="1" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.lottoData" col="2" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.codiceCont" col="3" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.qtyUntPri" col="4" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.studioCieco" col="5" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
        <label [text]="item.qty" col="6" [row]="item.row" fontSize="24px"></label>
      </ng-container>
    </GridLayout>
```

**Note**: Either use string extrapolation `{{ expression }}` or binding using square brackets `[]`, but not both, and of course, no need for the comma after `col="x"` inside the `<label>` property.

Comment: Welcome. If this is useful, please vote up and select as the chosen answer. Thanks.